# How to read a CSV file with multiple headers into two DataFrames in pandas, one with the headers and one with the data with some headers removed?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a CSV file that has a few first rows representing the header. I would like to read it into two `DataFrames`. The first `DataFrame` should contain the entire contents of the file, except some headers. The second `DataFrame` should contain all headers.

Example. Let's assume that we have the CSV file called `mh.csv`, with the two first rows representing the headers.

```
Name,Height,Age
"",Metres,""
A,-1,25
B,95,-1
```

The first `DataFrame` should contain the entire contents of the `mh.csv` file, with the second row removed:

```
    Name  Height  Age    

0   A     NaN     25.0
1   B     95.0    NaN
```

The second `DataFrame` should contain both first rows of the `mh.csv` file:

```
    Name  Height   Age
0         Metres
```

What is a recommended approach of doing such a split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#read file with MultiIndex
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=[0,1], na_values=[-1,''])
    print (df)
                Name Height                Age
  Unnamed: 0_level_1 Metres Unnamed: 2_level_1
0                  A    NaN               25.0
1                  B   95.0                NaN


df1 = df.copy()
#remove first level of MultiIndex
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(1)
print (df1)
  Name  Height   Age
0    A     NaN  25.0
1    B    95.0   NaN

#select first level of MultiIndex
a = df.columns.get_level_values(level=0)
#select second level of MultiIndex and replace Unnamed
b = df.columns.get_level_values(level=1).str.replace('Un.*','')
#DataFrame constructor
df2 = pd.DataFrame([a, b])
print (df2)
      0       1    2
0  Name  Height  Age
1        Metres
```

Comment: I would like to the second DataFrame to have the first row of the header of the original DataFrame. How about a Series instead of DataFrame?

Comment: Then is possible use `df2 = pd.DataFrame([a, b], columns=a)`. I am thinking about `Series`, not sure if need it `pd.Series([a.tolist(), b.tolist()])`